# How do I read from a text file in Python 3.9.6?

Tags: python-3.x, readline

How do I read from a text file in Python? This seems like it should be simple but I cannot even open the file without an error. I am using Visual Studio Code and both files are within the same folder directory (HelloWorld.txt and firstProgram.py) My code:

```
f = open('HelloWorld.txt', 'r')
print(f.readline())
f.close()
```

Error message:

```
PS C:\Users\Alex> & 
C:/Users/Alex/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe 
c:/Users/Alex/Desktop/Code/firstProgram.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\Alex\Desktop\Code\firstProgram.py", line 1, in <module>
f = open('HelloWorld.txt', 'r')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'HelloWorld.txt'
PS C:\Users\Alex>
```

Image:

[firstProgramAttemptInVSC][1]

My first time posting here so any tips on question etiquette is appreciated! Thanks.

---

SOLUTIONS FOUND: 

 1. Reinstalled Python into the desired working directory. This solved the issue

2. Path issue solved with following updated code:

```
f = open('C:\\Users\\Alex\\Desktop\\Code\\HelloWorld.txt', 'r')
print(f.read())
f.close()
```

I had set the path to `C:\\Users\\Alex\\Desktop\\Code\\HelloWorld.txt`

Comment: have a look at [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) for proper file path handling

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your issue is related with path. You can try with full path of file

Comment: try this path C:\\Users\Alex\Desktop\Code\HelloWorld.txt

Comment: if it is not working try this as well C:\\Users\\Alex\\Desktop\\Code\\HelloWorld.txt

Answer (score 1):

Presumably it's looking in your *working directory*, shown to be `C:\Users\Alex>` above, rather than whatever directory the script happens to live in.

Either give a complete path to the file, or set the working directory appropriately, or let the user specify where the file is.

Comment: I have tried changing work directory but get errors (see update). I also tried specifying the full path `C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\Code\HelloWorld.txt` and I get the following error in VSC: `SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> & C:/Users/Alex/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe c:/Users/Alex/Desktop/Code/firstProgram.py
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    & C:/Users/Alex/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe c:/Users/Alex/Desktop/Code/firstProgram.py
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax` Also I'm not sure what you mean by your third option "let the user specify where the file is"

Comment: You can't just put backslashes in strings like that; they signify escape characters.

Comment: Solved the the path issue with 'C:\\Users\\Alex\\Desktop\\Code\\HelloWorld.txt'